# Under autolayout, how do I show a loading wheel until a UIImageView has an image available?

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I have a lot of old-fashioned code that uses hard-coded frames, and I'm in the process of replacing it with storyboards and auto layout.

Part of this old code would show a `UIActivityIndicatorView` inside a table cell while retrieving an image from the Internet. Once the image was ready, the loading wheel was removed from its superview and replaced with a `UIImageView` holding the new image.

How can I achieve the same thing using storyboards and auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an activity indicator outlet and assign the constraints accordingly.
2. Then, when you start loading the image, run `[[self activityIndicator] startAnimating]` and `[[self activityIndicator] stopAnimating]` when it finishes.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I thought auto layout wouldn't allow me to superimpose an activity indicator over an image view. But it does.

Answer (score 0):

Is removing and adding a requirement? It seems like hiding would be easier.

Put both views in the prototype cell in Interface Builder and setup their constraints. Use a custom cell class to hold the image and activity views (I'll call mine `JLTTableViewCell`). As part of this setup, I'll imagine a `JLTDataObject` that has an image and a method to load an image which uses a completion block.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    JLTTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    JLTDataObject *object = self.data[indexPath.row];

    cell.activityIndicatorView.hidden = object.image != nil;
    cell.loadedImageView.hidden = object.image == nil;
    cell.loadedImageView.image = object.image;

    if (object.image == nil) {
        [cell.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
        [object loadImageWithCompletion:^{
            [cell.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

This will first load the cell hiding the image view and showing the activity indicator. It then loads the image. Upon completion, it reloads that cell. This causes `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called again, but this time the image is loaded.

In this second time through, the image exists so the image view is shown and the activity indicator is hidden.

Answer (score -1):

you need to write you code in background queue as data will be loaded fast but loading image might take time.
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return arrImages.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  
 NSString *cellIdentifire = @"tblCell";
   
 CustomCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifire];
    
if (Cell == nil) {
      
  Cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifire]; 
    }
    [Cell.contentLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Index Path :%d",(int)indexPath.row]];
    [Cell.viewImage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    if (Cell.viewImage.image == nil) {
        [Cell.indicateActivate startAnimating];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[arrImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [Cell.viewImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
        if (Cell.viewImage.image != nil) {
            [Cell.indicateActivate stopAnimating];
        }
    });

```
return Cell;<br>
```

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   
 [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
arrImages = @[@"http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110302225528/rift/images/7/7f/AWESOME_FACE!!!.png",
                  @"http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjBSUc3q9eHq5b7uby1wPEowXQW_gAUWi3uKmMlgv8Vz5diwAKDA",
                  @"http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwMjSiu59v8eqNC8W19lGeqynFVXeZEnLuV0qhJNdk3La_M-sp",
                  @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Tricoloring.png",
                  @"http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSwRRSVAmwLBsO-Qdp4r0uPbppPviYFDCiw9DP8v8_bL4uWUF_",
                  @"http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20131105231053/avp/images/thumb/4/4a/Photographer_Barnstar.png/505px-Photographer_Barnstar.png",
                  @"http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQmWPQ32AfUo6PnGujNX3rR6FTPiICnNqQP7r35XjmzEjWiRJ4y"];
}

Set Hides when Stopped in attribute inspector for activity indicator.
[image]